# Mi función no devuelve bien el valor(kotlin)

Tags: kotlin, arraylist, funcion

Tengo una función que lee los usuarios de una colección en Firestore y quiero que me los devuelva en un ArrayList de Usuarios. El caso es que lee bien los valores, los imprimo mediante un Toast y se ejecuta correctamente, el problema es que no me mete el valor en el return.He pensado en meter un ArrayList como variable interna e ir metiendole valores en el OnSuccess pero no hay manera. Alguien sabe como arreglarlo?Gracias

```
fun usuariosNoVerificados(context: Context): List<Usuario> {
    var usuarios = ArrayList<Usuario>()


    FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("usuarios").whereEqualTo("verificado", false)
        .get().addOnSuccessListener { result ->

            for (document in result) {
                val auxPlan = "" + document.getLong("plan")
                val auxAdmin = "" + document.getBoolean("admin")
                val auxVerificado = "" + document.getBoolean("verificado")
                val actual: Usuario = Usuario(
                    "" + document.getString("nombre"), "" +
                            document.getString("apellidos"), "" +
                            document.getString("dni"), "" +
                            document.getString("email"),
                    document.getLong("plan")!!.toByte(),
                    auxAdmin.toBoolean(), auxVerificado.toBoolean()
                )
                usuarios.add(
                    actual
                )
                //ArrayList como variable interna que tampoco funciona
                usuariosSinVerificar.add(actual)

            }
            Toast.makeText(
                context,
                "Tamaño en el OnSuccess " + usuarios.size,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
            ).show()


        }.addOnFailureListener {

        }
    Toast.makeText(context, "Tamaño al devolver " + usuarios.size, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    return usuarios.toList()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**El problema es que el proceso para obtener los usuarios es asíncrono**, por lo tanto, será difícil que puedas obtener el resultado correcto.

Lo que debes realizar es obtener el resultado dentro de `addOnSuccessListener`, en caso de falla se llamaría `addOnFailureListener`.

Dentro de `addOnSuccessListener` debes llamar el siguiente proceso que necesitas, ejemplo:

```
val docRef = db.collection("usuarios").whereEqualTo("verificado", false).get()
        .addOnSuccessListener { result ->
            for (document in result) {
                valoresReturn.add("" + "${document.id}")
            }

            //*Obtiene usuarios, llama proceso.
             procesaUsuarios();

        }.addOnFailureListener { exception ->
            Toast.makeText(this, "No se pudieron extrar los documentos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show() 

        }
```